# How to click a link using ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following requirement:

- Need to download a document if generated properly by a third party service.
- If byte stream is not pdf then throw error.
- To achieve the same, I call the action to trigger document generation. I f document is sucessfully generated, I would like to trigger a click on the link mentioned below.
- I am doing this because if I use the href link directly it expects a Response back with pdf, in case of error it renders a new page or new tab. Requirement is to show the error on the same screen without reload.
- I read many options on internet and it says i cannot render the error on the same screen without having two independent calls to server side.
- Hence, I need to click on a href link generated by a custom tag which generates a href link when page is rendered.

  `<abs:resourceLink id="printQuoteResourceLink" action="downloadSaveQuote"
                     label="#{msg.quotePrint}"/>`

this would render a href when page is loaded:

```
<a id="pb42583:pageform:printQuoteResourceLink" 
   name="pb42583:pageform:printQuoteResourceLink"
   href="/broker/broker/Home/Buy/ProductSimple?portal%3AwindowState=normal&amp;navigationalstate=JBPNS_rO0ABXceAAlleGVjdXRpb24AAAABAARlMXM0AAdfX0VPRl9f&amp;portal%3AcomponentId=8878e340-f05e-47d3-bdcb-42d29a6c62b3&amp;portal%3AcacheLevel=PAGE&amp;resourcestate=JBPNS_rO0ABXdyAA5zcHJpbmdSZXNvdXJjZQAAAAEAAAAMc3ByaW5nQWN0aW9uAAAAAQARZG93bmxvYWRTYXZlUXVvdGUABGRhdGUAAAABAA0xNDUxNTYzNTI2ODc0AAlleGVjdXRpb24AAAABAARlMXM0AAdfX0VPRl9f&amp;portal%3Atype=resource&amp;portal%3AportletMode=view">Print quote
</a><script type="text/javascript">
```

- On click of button action is called which would trigger document generation and i would store the document in bean. When response is back I will check if value in the bean is true. If true i need to click the link generated.
- I can use ajax and jquery to achieve this.

My current code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="panelPrintQuote">
   <div class="bordered button">
      <h:commandButton class="bordered button"  style="width: 154px;float:left;margin-left:640px !important; font-size:1em !important; 
            Padding: 0px 7px 0px 0px;" id="printQuoteCommandButton" value="#{msg.quotePrint}" action="generateSaveQuote" >
            <a4j:ajax render="panelPrintQuoteResource"/>
    </h:commandButton>
    <!--    <abs:resourceLink id="printQuote" action="downloadSaveQuote"
                        label="#{msg.quotePrint}" image="/resources/images/transparent_image.png"/> -->
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup id="panelPrintQuoteResource" rendered="#{bnl_WebPageConfirmation.documentAvailable}">

   <abs:resourceLink id="printQuoteResourceLink" action="downloadSaveQuote"
        label="#{msg.quotePrint}" style="display:none;" image="/resources/images/transparent_image.png"/>

<h:outputScript>
 //<![CDATA[ 
   window.onload= $('a[href$="printQuoteResourceLink"]').click(function(){});
//]]>
 </h:outputScript>
```

Comment: $(a).trigger('click'); should be enough to click the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trigger('click')` since the element already bound using `.click()`

```
var a = $('a[href$="printQuoteResourceLink"]'); // cache the element for better performance
a.click(function(){
       a.trigger('click');
});
```

But you also use

```
$('a[href$="printQuoteResourceLink"]')[0].click();
```

`[0]` will get the DOM object which has the `.click()` function

Another way is using `.get(0)` to get the DOM object, same as `[0]`

```
$('a[href$="printQuoteResourceLink"]').get(0).click();
```